Enabling conversation memory for Pandas or CSV Agent in Langchain 0.2.10
I am trying to create a pandas agent in Langchain to respond to queries on very large numerical tabular information (dataframes and SQL Servers). I have managed to tune my prompts and parameters to generate the right answers, but I have not been able to add memory so that the user can chat about previous questions and responses.
I have reviewed and tried all information in these links:
https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/memory/agent_with_memory/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaQ6XrhEvjI
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/17509
But as you can see, not even on the official Langchain website is there memory for a pandas agent or a CSV agent (which uses the create_pandas_agent function).
I have tried the code in these Stack Overflow posts:
How to add conversational memory to pandas toolkit agent?
add memory to create_pandas_dataframe_agent in Langchain
without any luck, as they do not seem to work with the newer version of Langchain, which is important as this newer version has improved interaction with the REPL Python environment, which is crucial for the agent.
My LLM is GPT3 OpenAI from Azure.
Currently, I am working with this code:
"""Agent for working with pandas objects."""
from typing import Any, List, Optional

from langchain.agents.agent import AgentExecutor
from langchain.agents import ZeroShotAgent
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackManager
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.llms.base import BaseLLM
from langchain.tools.python.tool import PythonAstREPLTool
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")

def create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
    llm: BaseLLM,
    df: Any,
    callback_manager: Optional[BaseCallbackManager] = None,
    prefix: str = "",
    suffix: str = "",
    input_variables: Optional[List[str]] = None,
    verbose: bool = False,
    return_intermediate_steps: bool = False,
    max_iterations: Optional[int] = 15,
    max_execution_time: Optional[float] = None,
    early_stopping_method: str = "force",
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> AgentExecutor:
    """Construct a pandas agent from an LLM and dataframe."""
    import pandas as pd

    if not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        raise ValueError(f"Expected pandas object, got {type(df)}")
    if input_variables is None:
        input_variables = ["df", "input", "agent_scratchpad"]
    tools = [PythonAstREPLTool(locals={"df": df})]
    
    PREFIX = """
            You are working with a pandas dataframe in Python. The name of the dataframe is `df`.
            You should use the tools below to answer the question posed of you:"""
    
    SUFFIX = """
            This is the result of `print(df.head())`:
            {df}
            Begin!
            {chat_history}
            Question: {input}
            {agent_scratchpad}"""

    prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
        tools, 
        prefix=PREFIX,
        suffix=SUFFIX, 
        input_variables=["df", "input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"]
    )
    
    partial_prompt = prompt.partial(df=str(df.head()))
    
    llm_chain = LLMChain(
        llm=llm,
        prompt=partial_prompt,
        callback_manager=callback_manager,
    )
    
    tool_names = [tool.name for tool in tools]
    
    agent = ZeroShotAgent(
        llm_chain=llm_chain,
        allowed_tools=tool_names,
        callback_manager=callback_manager,
        **kwargs,
    )
    return AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
        agent=agent,
        tools=tools,
        verbose=verbose,
        return_intermediate_steps=return_intermediate_steps,
        max_iterations=max_iterations,
        max_execution_time=max_execution_time,
        early_stopping_method=early_stopping_method,
        callback_manager=callback_manager,
        memory=memory
    )

This code is found on GitHub: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3106
But it works with a ZeroShotAgent not with a pandas agent which has the tools and the OpenAI tools to work as much as the pandas agent to retrieve answers based on previous questions and answers.
To make an example, I'm using the above code with the Titanic sample dataset.

First, I ask: "Do we have a column to determine the sex of the
survivors?" The bot responds that yes, the column is SEX; we also have
AGE and the class of the ticket.
Then I ask: "What is the percentage of those columns?" The bot
responds: "Sorry, please be more specific, what column do you want to
filter?"
I ask: "What was my first question and your response?" The bot
responds: "Sorry, I don't have a track of our conversation or
dataframe df."

How can I enable conversational memory so that the pandas agent remembers previous questions and responses? It needs to be compatible with langchain 0.2.10 and using the pandas agent or the cvs agent.

I guess you don't have conversation memory in pandas agent.
